# Service running on RHEL7.5 is not running on RHEL8 (httpd service)

Tags: apache, rhel, rhel7

I have service which was working fine with RHEL 7.5, now I have upgraded to RHEL 8 and same service is failing with below status:

```
Service.service - LSB: Web Server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/Service; generated)
Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Mon 2020-04-06 12:02:21 IST; 38min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 403 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/Service start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Web Server...
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain Service[403]: httpd (pid 29434) already running
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Service.service: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acquired through unsafe symlink chain:
/usr/local/apache/logs/Service.pid
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Service.service: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acquired through unsafe symlink chain:
/usr/local/apache/logs/Service.pid
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Service.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Web Server
```

THis is my Service unit placed under /etc/init.d/Service, same is done for RHEL 7.5 but there this service is working and in RHEL 8 it is not. One more thing here to note is web server is working as expected although giving me this error.

```
    #!/bin/sh
#
# chkconfig: 345 97 03
# description:Web Server
# processname: httpd
# config: /usr/local/Test/apache/conf/httpd.conf
# pidfile: /usr/local/Test/apache/logs/httpd.pid

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: Service
# Required-Start: $remote_fs $network $syslog
# Should-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start: 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6`enter code here`
# Short-Description: Web Server
# Description: Web Server
### END INIT INFO

LANG=en_US.iso88591
export LANG

BASEDIR=/usr/local/Test/apache
PATH=$BASEDIR/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
export PATH

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$BASEDIR/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

inst=/usr/local/Test
MIBDIRS=$inst/mibs
export MIBDIRS

case $1 in
start)
  apachectl start
  ;;
stop)
  apachectl stop
  ;;
restart)
  apachectl restart
  ;;
*)
  echo "usage: $0 { start | stop | restart }"
  ;;
esac
```

Plz help me into this.

Comment: Did you (or someone from your org) write the `Service` file yourself? Notice [help/on-topic] for what's on topic on Stackoverflow, otherwise you'll find appropriate sites in the Stackexchange network, e.g. for server administration. You'll need to add more information though - "_something_ doesn't work" isn't very descriptive if we don't know what _something_ refers to (e.g. post your `Service` file, preferably as a [mcve]. But first: Edit this question to make it on-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks Olaf Kock, I have not written service file but My colleague did. I have posted same in question itself. Plz see that

Comment: Did you notice `Apr 06 12:02:21 localhost.localdomain Service[403]: httpd (pid 29434) already running` in the output? You are trying to start something that's already started?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know that PID is already running (No issue there), but my concern is why I am getting those errors: Service.service: Refusing to accept PID outside of service control group, acquired through unsafe symlink chain:
/usr/local/apache/logs/Service.pid

Comment: This question has been resolved here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578410/service-running-on-rhel7-5-is-not-running-on-rhel8-httpd-service . Thank you